# Create a subsite of Math.SE where members could show up with their discoveries.

Tags: discussion, proposal

There are many people who make little discoveries or re-discoveries in the criteria of Maths and they want to share these with the world. A convenient way to make this available would be the creation of a subsite of Math.SE where members could share their discoveries from little to bigger level. Experts on this site could judge their work, detect their flaws and correct them. Votes would honor the inventor and it would be a source of motivation. It will prevent Math.SE from getting off-topic questions also.

Comment: The idea of the stackexchange network is to answer questions.  If users have a discovery that is not really a question.  If they have a question about their proof, then they can certainly ask those questions already.  MathOverflow handles research level mathematics.  There is also a tag for this, proof-verification.

Comment: On a side note, I suspect that your down votes are not so much because this is a bad question, but because they disagree with the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, downvotes, here, show disagreement. Not a big deal. :)

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the [Mathematics Community Blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/).  (You might also want to read the [Community Blog FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13903/18398).)

Comment: This answer reads excessively implicit and curt, but it is precisely the answer to the question. Such a subsite already exists. If a member wanted to show a mathematical discovery, our blog would be glad to post it, quality of post of course being necessary. Posts there are thorough, and reviewed, they are criticized, and corrections are occasionally made even after the posting. Posters get input as well in comments. It meets all criteria as the already extant solution to this proposal.