# A link to Blog FAQ should be available on the blog page

Tags: feature-request, blog

While trying to put a post on the community blog I found that there is no link to the [blog FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13903/community-blog-faq) on the blog itself. This is strange, since if a new user wishes to contribute to the blog there should be a link to guide him/her to the appropriate page containing information regarding the publication process.

Can a link of this kind be put up on the blog page? If so, what is the process to request that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a link to the blog faq in the blog's [about page](http://math.blogoverflow.com/about/):

> If you have a suggestion for a post here, see [the Blog FAQ on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13903/community-blog-faq)....

---

It might be nice to have a link to the faq from the main page, perhaps as an addition to the sidebar text

> This is a community blog for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). More community blogs are available at [Blog Overflow](http://blogoverflow.com/).

I'll have to look into if/how this can be accomplished.